# MudBlazor Mudtable RowEditing Datetime

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I use from mudblazor the MudTable. It displays the data perfectly.

I like to edit it inline. In my model there is a DateTime field I want to edit and set.

After some juggling around, I see a datepicker, a timepicker, but I can't seem to figure out how to edit this inline as a legal date and time format and combine them back to the data-sourcefield.

Can you help me with some samplecode to achieve that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `<MudTd>` tag, add the `MudDatePicker` and `MudTimePicker`:

```html
<MudTd>
  <MudDatePicker 
    Date="@context.DateTime.Date" 
    DateChanged="@(d => this.DateChanged(d.Value, context))"/>

  <MudTimePicker
    Time="@context.DateTime.TimeOfDay"
    TimeChanged="@(t => this.TimeChanged(t.Value, context))"/>
</MudTd>
```

and implement the `DateChanged(...)` and `TimeChanged(...)` in your own code.

A demo:

```cs
@page "/"

<MudTable Items="@this.elements">
  <ToolBarContent>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Elements</MudText>
  </ToolBarContent>
  <HeaderContent>
    <MudTh>Id</MudTh>
    <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
    <MudTh>DateTime</MudTh>
  </HeaderContent>
  <RowTemplate>
    <MudTd>@context.Id</MudTd>
    <MudTd>@context.Name</MudTd>
    <MudTd>
      <MudDatePicker Date="@context.DateTime.Date" DateChanged="@(d => this.DateChanged(d.Value, context))"/>
      <MudTimePicker Time="@context.DateTime.TimeOfDay" TimeChanged="@(t => this.TimeChanged(t.Value, context))"/>
    </MudTd>
  </RowTemplate>
  <PagerContent>
    <MudTablePager />
  </PagerContent>
</MudTable>

<MudText Color="Color.Primary">@this.log</MudText>

@code {
  private string log = string.Empty;
  private List<Element> elements = new();

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    this.elements = new List<Element>
    {
      new() { Id = 1, Name = "First", DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(1) },
      new() { Id = 2, Name = "Second", DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(2) },
      new() { Id = 3, Name = "Third", DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(3) },
    };
  }

  public class Element
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
  }

  private void DateChanged(DateTime date, Element element)
  {
    this.SetDateTime(date, element.DateTime.TimeOfDay, element);
  }

  private void TimeChanged(TimeSpan time, Element element)
  {
    this.SetDateTime(element.DateTime.Date, time, element);
  }

  private void SetDateTime(DateTime date, TimeSpan time, Element element)
  {
    element.DateTime = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);

    this.log = $"New datetime for element with Id {element.Id}: {element.DateTime}";
  }
}
```

Try it online: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/caGROlvFgrXENaMD

Comment: Hello Bart, 
The way you explain it, with the example, is so simple that I directly feel a bit silly I haven't approached it this way. 
Clearly a moment of narrow vision, of a freelance developer working alone.  And it already works.  
Thank you for your support.
I hope I can support you in return sometime.